# How to use external Javascript to use onclick event to change document.title?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This code runs immediately once the page is loaded. The onclick event is completely ignored by javascript. What is an easy fix for this because like youtube when you play a video the document.title is updated with a speaker. I want to learn to do that with external javascript because I can do it with internal javascript in the html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Animation </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animationcss.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<script src="animation.js"></script>



<input id="changeButton" type="button" value="Change" ></input>
```

/*External Javascript*/

```
      var element = document.getElementById("changeButton");
      element.onclick = textChange("changetothis");

      function textChange(text){
      document.title = text;
```

}

Comment: You're calling the function, not referencing it, it should be `element.onclick = textChange;` and then you figure out another way to pass the text

Comment: Clarification on adeneo's comment: When you use () after a function name, it will invoke the function. When you invoke a function on the right hand side of an assignment operator, it will assign the left hand side value to the RETURN value of the function that was invoked. Since you are not explicitly returning a value from your textChange function, javascript returns undefined by default. Therefore element.onclick === undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling the function after the document is loaded by placing the script tag below the object or making $(document).ready() function,
this code works fine with me

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title> Animation </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="changeButton" type="button" value="Change" ></input>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <body>
  </html>
```

and the script is

```
  var el = document.getElementById("changeButton");
  el.onclick = function(){
    textChange("changetothis");
  }

  function textChange(text){
   document.title = text;
  }
```

Comment: Yes it worked like a charm. I think it was because where i placed the script in the html. Thank you again! I used your javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired effect by using an anonymous function, like so:

```
document.getElementById("changeButton").onclick = function () {
  document.title = newTitle;
}
```

The variable 'newTitle' should be declared & initalized above this code somewhere in order for it to work.

Comment: This is what i changed it to: var newTitle = "Change2This";

document.getElementById("changeButton").onclick = function(){
    document.title = newTitle;
}                                                                                                                                   But it did not work.

Comment: In your HTML, the `script` tag should be moved to below of the `input` tag, as pointed out in the post below mine. Generally, `script` elements should always be the last elements in the HTML body.